# UI Router: get params of "to" and "from" state with $transitions service

Tags: angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use `$transitions` service instead of `$stateParams` like [there](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events) for listening on state changing, but can't get state params. I'm using property of [StateObject](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/state.stateobject.html#params), but instead of getting for example `{id: 123}`, i got `{id: e}`, where `e` is a object in which i can't find a value. Anybody help with this ?

```
$transitions.onStart({ }, function(trans) {
    console.log(trans.$from().params);
}
```

I noticed that `trans.params()` return "to" state params.

Answer (score 12):

`trans.$from().params` will get you **from** state parameters *declaration*.

`trans.params('from')` will get you their actual *values*

---

Probably what you need is:

```js
$transitions.onStart({ }, function(trans) {
    console.log(trans.params('from'));
}
```

Please refer to documentation here

State params
https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#params

Transition params
https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#params